# CSS: Reposition remaining grid cells after onclick event removes some

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid

I'm amateur with CSS grid layout. What I'm trying to do is removing some elements in the grid with an `onclick()` event, and making the remaining elements reposition and get in the shape of the removed ones like this:

[image]

My codes remove "A" from the grid, but unable to change the shape of "B" and "C". Is there a way to achieve this with css or very simple js? I will have many other buttons to remove many other cells, so I'm trying to keep the codes as short as possible.

HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="grid a">Grid A</div>
  <div class="grid b">Grid B</div>
  <div class="grid c">Grid C</div>

  <div class="grid a">Grid A</div>
  <div class="grid b">Grid B</div>
  <div class="grid c">Grid C</div>

  <div class="grid a">Grid A</div>
  <div class="grid b">Grid B</div>
  <div class="grid c">Grid C</div>

</div>

<div class="button" onclick="hide()">Hide Grid A</div>
```

JS

```
function hide() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
  var i;
  for (i=0; i<element.length; i++) {
    if (element[i].style.display) {
      element[i].style.display = null;
    }
    else {element[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  counter-reset: div;
}
.grid {
  border: solid;
}
.grid:nth-child(6n + 1), .grid:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  grid-column: auto /span 2;
  grid-row: auto /span 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hidden the elements from the view, but that doesn't change the how the grid is processed and setup.

You need to actually remove the elements from the DOM.

Check out https://replit.com/@cmorrreplit/TestingGridChange for a working example.

Comment: I wish there was a css solution, but thank you for this method anyway. However the button doesn't bring "A" back like mine does. Can you make it too please?

Comment: There are many ways you could approach capturing the deleted element's original position in the DOM. My suggestion (for your HTML in particular because it's so straightforward) would something like: store an array of variables pointing to deleted items' preceding sibling element, or parent element if there is no preceding sibling. Then, use the `insertAdjacentHTML` method to re-add `a` elements.

Comment: I have updated the code example @ https://replit.com/@cmorrreplit/TestingGridChange.